# Mac Server setup for small office

Tags: mysql, mac

We have a Mac Mini with OSX server for our small web design company's office. We want to move toward a local setup and to then push up to the live server. In the past I have used MAMP PRO and Sequel Pro to create an environment on my personal computer.

Our setup is basically 1 Mac Mini with Server OSX and then 5 iMacs. I would like to be able to type in `http://clients/client-name` and pull up the sites from all of our computers.

My initial plan is to mount the the individual sites with Transmit 4, have CodeKit watch it for preprocessing (SASS), and Sublime Text as our editor.

I know I should ask a specific answerable question, but the real question is: what is the the best way for us to set up our server to our sites? We do a lot of custom WordPress builds so Apache and mySQL are key.

What could I can read about? Everything I have found is *"OSX server, does it all - have fun!"*.

Another issue is how to push it live with Beanstalk, maybe, and migrate DB pro?

Comment: You will definitely have to be more specific.  It isn't clear what exactly you are confused about, or what alternatives you are wondering about, even.

Comment: Sorry about that. I hope to be able to clarify soon.

Comment: I wouldn't touch OS X for a server...it's just not manageable enough.

Comment: What would you suggest then? I know that there are many other options - and If I had reason to use those options, I might go in that direction, but what we need seems so very simple.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need MAMP on every iMac.
2. You need an Apple Time Capsule Router/Network Storage Drive.
3. Tell MAMP to look for the Site Files on the Time Capsule.
4. Import the MySQL Database for Each Website into phpMyAdmin on MAMP.
5. Run MAMP on each iMac.
6. Go to localhost:8888 in your Browser.
7. Click on the Site you want to Edit.

**NOTE:** Name the Site Folder for Each Website.